How can I access submodule's classes from inner packages?
I was not aware that cross visibility quirkiness remained even on published artifacts, so I've found these to be some rules of thumb I wasn't aware:

Transient Transitive dependencies are not accessible. (as opposed to what some
sources have said) I was told that if B implements A, I would have
access to A from C when C implements B... this was not the case
after testing. (Because of #1, I was structuring the artifacts
dividing them in submodules, classifying them based on degree of
outer dependance.)

Artifact submodules can ONLY be accessed directly under main/java.
If a class' path goes deeper than this, the class will have access
to none of the submodule's contents:


On build.gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation('io.github.org:anartifact-submodule:1.0.0')
}

From src/main/java/some_package/DeepClass.java
package some_package;

import io.github.org.anartifact_submodule.SomeClass;
// import anartifact_submodule.SomeClass;
// import submodule.SomeClass;

public class DeepClass {
   SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
}


"cannot resolve [ io | anartifact_submodule | submodule | SomeClass ] symbol"

Now from main/java/SurfaceClass.java:
class SurfaceClass {
   SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
}

No issue, no import needed.
How can I access a submodule's content from inside a package?

Regarding your first point, I assume you mean transitive instead of transient and depends on instead of implements? And note that in Gradle, with the Java Library Plugin, project B has to define project A as an api dependency (instead of an implementation dependency) if project C, which depends on project B, is going to have compile-time access to project A without project C defining a direct dependency on project A. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph.

Thanks for the correction, After looking at the table, I wonder if the Maven | Gradle build tools may be able to even perform "dependency mediation" when using implementation my guess is that no(?) since the dependant binary is "intrinsic" to the artifact (maybe because of compiler inlines etc...), but this would also mean that using api would make the artifact slower since compiling optimizations would be prohibited as long as forced by an implementation.
I believe using api is the best option tbh.

You should typically only use api when your project is exposing (in its own public API) types from the dependency. Otherwise, you should use implementation. And as I understand it, transitive (not direct) implementation dependencies are not placed on the class-path/module-path during compilation, and so should not affect compiler performance. Also, note the Java compiler does very little optimizing. In fact, the only optimization I'm aware of is that it inlines compile-time constants (and nothing else). Pretty much all performance optimizations are done by the JIT at run-time.

I think everything I did was just overcomplicating myself for nothing since implementation was already pruning out unused material... and what's worst it seems that "Dependency Mediation" is still able to access inner artifact dependencies set by the artifact producer via implementation during buildup.
